# Combine 2 SQL tables on primary key - update existing and insert new rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, dml

I have a huge XML file (About 60 GB), which I need to extract data from. *I get a new updated XML file once a week, and I need to update the data in my database*. It's a file with some information about each car in Denmark, so information of each element might change from one week to the other. I've managed to create a program which can read though this file and extract each element and parse it to my database. It currently have 8,400,000 elements in the XML file. First I tried uploading each row to my database once at a time and I only managed to insert about 300 rows / sec. It would then take about 7-8 hours to insert all the 8.4 million rows. I therefore changed my reader to store 5000 records in a temporary data-table and then bulk insert all 5000 rows at once. This increased my read/insert rate to about 7000 rows / sec. A huge improvement. Now I upload all elements in less than 20 min. My problem is I can't update a table when using bulk insert. Some of the elements are listed twice in the XML file for some reason, so I need to remove duplicates in my table before i add the primary key.

My current solution is to create 2 tables in my database: dbo.eStatistik and dbo.eStatistikLoad

I will then use my reader to extract all 8,400,000 elements from the new XML file and bulk insert them to the dbo.eStatistikLoad. Once all elements are in dbo.eStatistikLoad I will remove all duplicate rows and then set the column (KoeretoejIdent) as my PRIMARY KEY. Once this is done I want to update each existing row in dbo.eStatistik with the data from dbo.eStatistikLoad and insert new rows in dbo.eStatistik with the data from dbo.eStatistikLoad.

Currently I can bulk insert and remove duplicate rows just fine, but I don't know how to update existing rows and insert new rows between 2 tables. As mentioned both tables have the primary key (KoeretoejIdent) after I've removed duplicates: I've tried these commands, but I keep getting an error:

```
INSERT
INTO    dbo.eStatistik
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.eStatistikLoad
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
        dbo.eStatistik.KoeretoejIdent = dbo.eStatistikLoad.KoeretoejIdent
        dbo.eStatistik.KoeretoejArtNavn = dbo.eStatistikLoad.KoeretoejArtNavn
        dbo.eStatistik.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn = dbo.eStatistikLoad.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn
```

I get the following error message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

I've also tried these two commands, but getting same error:

```
/* COMMAND 1 */
REPLACE INTO dbo.eStatistik SELECT * FROM dbo.eStatistikLoad

/* COMMAND 2 */
INSERT IGNORE
  INTO dbo.eStatistik 
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.eStatistikLoad
     ;
```

I get same error when using both commands:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 70
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
```

Comment: Your error message looks like SQL Server.  Your table references and use of XML also suggest SQL Server.  Yet, your query is using MySQL syntax.  `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is specific to MySQL.

Comment: Having a separate table to load the xml data is fine.  In fact, it's a frequently used approach.  The concept is called "staging".  On to your problem, you need something other than a database generated value to identify the records in your main table.  This being a car database, maybe the Vehicle Identification Number would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx) command. It has been supported since MSSQL 2008 and it was designed for scenarios like yours. I don't know are details of your solution so here is only a sketch of the query:

```
MERGE dbo.eStatistik AS T
USING dbo.eStatistikLoad AS S ON (T.KoeretoejIdent = S.KoeretoejIdent) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(KoeretoejIdent, KoeretoejArtNavn, KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn) 
            VALUES(S.KoeretoejIdent, S.KoeretoejArtNavn, S.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET 
         T.KoeretoejIdent = S.KoeretoejIdent,
         T.KoeretoejArtNavn = S.KoeretoejArtNavn,
         T.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn = S.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn;
```

MERGE command will allow you to do much more than in the above example e.g. to delete records. Here is another [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) worth reading with examples of using MERGE.

Comment: Hello Michal, I get following error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.

Comment: Yea, i saw this, but when I removed this i get this new error: Incorrect syntax near 'T'.

Comment: I think i solved the problem! Had to add ',' at the end of each UPDATE and a ';' at the last one. Code is executing now. I'll check after. If this is the problem, would you mind updating your first answer! Thank you so much for your help!